# Question related to probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A and B are two weak students of the course “Probability Theory” and their chances of solving a problem in
“Probability Theory” correctly are 1/6 and 1/8, respectively. If the probability of their making a common error is
1/525 and they obtain the same answer, find the probability that their answer is correct.

I don't understand how to proceed with this question. Is the probability of common error relevant? Any solutions/tips welcome. Thank you.

Comment: It is worth pointing out the distinction between the phrase "making a common error" and "both making an error (but possibly different errors)."  If all wrong answers were the same... for example in the case of a true/false quiz, you can learn that the probability of both making an error is at least $\frac{5}{6}+\frac{7}{8}-1=\frac{17}{24}\approx 0.701$ and at most $\frac{5}{6}\approx 0.833$ which would have contradicted the value of $\frac{1}{525}$ which lies well outside of that range.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. The given values are compatible with the *a priori* probability of both of them solving the problem correctly lying anywhere between $0$ and $\frac18$. Correspondingly, the probability that they solved the problem correctly given that they obtained the same answer could lie anywhere between $0$ and $\frac{\frac18}{\frac18+\frac1{525}}=\frac{525}{533}\approx98.5\%$. Are you perhaps missing an independence assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event that person A got the question right, and $B$ the event that person B got the question right.

Let $C$ be the event that person $A$ and $B$ got the same answer.

We are told the following values in the question:

$Pr(A)=\frac{1}{6},~Pr(B)=\frac{1}{8},~Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C)=\frac{1}{525}$

It is heavily implied from context that $Pr(C\mid A\cap B) = 1$ and that $Pr(C\mid A\cap B^c)=Pr(C\mid A^c\cap B)=0$.  After all, if $A$ and $B$ both got the right answer, we can assume that the answer was the same (*invalid assumption in the case of questions have multiple different right answers*).  Further, if $A$ got a right answer and $B$ did not, then we can assume that their answers were different, and similarly so if $B$ had the right answer while $A$ didn't.

We are tasked with calculating $Pr(A\cap B\mid C)$

---

To continue, we might try to approach directly via definitions

$$Pr(A\cap B\mid C) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{Pr(C)}$$

Noting everything from above, this can simplify to

$$\dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(A\cap B)+Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C)}$$

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any way to calculate $Pr(A\cap B)$ from the given information however so we are stuck here.  If we were to assume that $A$ and $B$'s correctness is independent of one another, then we could expand $Pr(A\cap B)$ as $Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ and continue, but this is a rather strong assumption that the problem doesn't imply that we should make.

If we were to continue anyways with that assumption, then this continues as:

$$\dfrac{Pr(A)\times Pr(B)}{Pr(A)\times Pr(B)+Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C)}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{525}}$$ which can then be simplified down to a single value.